# catch a specific element from another site and display

Tags: php, dom, curl

How can I get a specific element on a page and show another?

I have this page http://www.supercounters.com/stats/1214936, i want to get this value:

```
<td 'class="span-5 visitortd">5,582 Visits</td>
```

And show in my page..

Like this :

```
Out: 5,582 Yesterday Visits
```

Actual code :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.supercounters.com/stats/1214936');

foreach($html->find('table') as $element) 
       echo $element->td . '<br>';
```

is the first time I'm trying to do this, and the current code is not working very well , I think we need to complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want is in `$html->find('td')`. Tag names don't become properties, you have to use `$element->find()` to access different elements.

Then to access the contents, you need to use `$element->plaintext`.

Comment: I made changes according your comment and Out is : Array
Array
Array

Comment: Have you read the documentation of how to use Simple HTML DOM? You need to use `->text` to access the text of an element.

Comment: Thanks guys, found a way to do this according your comments